# Creating Menu Entries for User Applications, Linux

Tags: java, rpm, fedora10

Hi I have created an rpm file. My application is completely java application. When I install my rpm I have to double click on Install.sh  (its a shell script file which start java application) my program starts. Now I want when i will install my rpm file an icon will be seen in desktop. and by clicking on that icon my application must start.

Whether I have to set anything in my .spec file

What I have to do to achieve this.

I am using Fedora10

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, RPM files install a `foo.desktop` file which will add a menu entry in the *Applications* menu.

Comment: RPM file is created depending on .spec file. I have installed my .rpm file no such thing happened

Answer (score 0):

You can take a rpm that is known to do this, extract it and read it's spec file
This will provide the required hints regrading the described behavior

### Mangling

1.
      Unpack rpm

```
  rpm2cpio httpd-2.0.52-32.ent.i386.rpm | cpio -idmv --no-absolute-filenames
```

2.
      View install scripts

```
  rpm -qp --scripts --triggers httpd-2.0.52-32.ent.i386.rpm
```

Also check http://susefaq.sourceforge.net/articles/rpm.html